# Joomla Hot Themes Carousel Blank Space

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, carousel

I have installed the HotThemes Carousel module in joomla and this is working fine so far. (unfortunately on localhost so can't share link)

The problem I am trying to fix is that for some reason when I click the next button it brings the next 4 images (like its set to move by 4 images or something) and as I only have 6 images in total, it shows up with blank spaces after the last 2 images.

What I would like is if the next button is pressed then this should bring the next image (so 1 at a time) and then just stop on the last image and then the prev button could be used to go the other way.

How can I do this?

```
/* jQuery Carousel 0.9.1
Copyright 2008-2009 Thomas Lanciaux and Pierre Bertet.
This software is licensed under the CC-GNU LGPL  
<http://creativecommons.org/licenses/LGPL/2.1/>
*/
;(function(jQuery){

    jQuery.fn.carousel = function(params){

        var params = jQuery.extend({
            direction: "horizontal",
            loop: false,
            dispItems: 5,
            pagination: false,
            paginationPosition: "inside",
            nextBtn: '<span>Next</span>',
            prevBtn: '<span>Previous</span>',
            btnsPosition: "inside",
            nextBtnInsert: "appendTo",
            prevBtnInsert: "prependTo",
            nextBtnInsertFn: false,
            prevBtnInsertFn: false,
            autoSlide: false,
            autoSlideInterval: 3000,
            delayAutoSlide: false,
            combinedClasses: false,
            effect: "slide",
            slideEasing: "swing",
            animSpeed: "normal",
            equalWidths: "true",
            callback: function(){},
            useAddress: false,
            adressIdentifier: "carousel"
        }, params);

        // Buttons position
        if (params.btnsPosition == "inside"){
            params.prevBtnInsert = "insertBefore";
            params.nextBtnInsert = "insertAfter";
        }

        // Slide delay
        params.delayAutoSlide = params.delayAutoSlide || params.autoSlideInterval;

        return this.each(function(){

            // Env object
            var env = {
                $elts: {},
                params: params,
                launchOnLoad: []
            };

            // Carousel main container
            env.$elts.carousel = jQuery(this).addClass("js");

            // Carousel content
            env.$elts.content = jQuery(this).children().css({position: "absolute", "top": 0});

            // Content wrapper
            env.$elts.wrap = env.$elts.content.wrap('<div class="carousel-wrap"></div>').parent().css({overflow: "hidden", position: "relative"});

            // env.steps object
            env.steps = {
                first: 0, // First step
                count: env.$elts.content.children().length // Items count
            };

            // Last visible step
            env.steps.last = env.steps.count - 1;

            // Prev Button
            if (jQuery.isFunction(env.params.prevBtnInsertFn)) {
                env.$elts.prevBtn = env.params.prevBtnInsertFn(env.$elts);

            } else { 
                env.$elts.prevBtn = jQuery(params.prevBtn)[params.prevBtnInsert](env.$elts.carousel);
            }

            // Next Button
            if (jQuery.isFunction(env.params.nextBtnInsertFn)) {
                env.$elts.nextBtn = env.params.nextBtnInsertFn(env.$elts);

            } else {
                env.$elts.nextBtn = jQuery(params.nextBtn)[params.nextBtnInsert](env.$elts.carousel);
            }

            // Add buttons classes / data
            env.$elts.nextBtn.addClass("carousel-control next carousel-next");
            env.$elts.prevBtn.addClass("carousel-control previous carousel-previous");

            // Bind events on next / prev buttons
            initButtonsEvents(env);

            // Pagination
            if (env.params.pagination) {
                initPagination(env);
            }

            // Address plugin
            initAddress(env);

            // On document load...
            jQuery(function(){

                // First item
                var $firstItem = env.$elts.content.children(":first");

                // Width 1/3 : Get default item width
                env.itemWidth = $firstItem.outerWidth();

                // Width 2/3 : Define content width
                if (params.direction == "vertical"){
                    env.contentWidth = env.itemWidth;

                } else {

                    if (params.equalWidths) {
                        env.contentWidth = env.itemWidth * env.steps.count;

                    } else {
                        env.contentWidth = (function(){
                                var totalWidth = 0;

                                env.$elts.content.children().each(function(){
                                    totalWidth += jQuery(this).outerWidth();
                                });

                                return totalWidth;
                            })();
                    }
                }

                // Width 3/3 : Set content width to container
                env.$elts.content.width( env.contentWidth );

                // Height 1/2 : Get default item height
                env.itemHeight = $firstItem.outerHeight();

                // Height 2/2 : Set content height to container
                if (params.direction == "vertical"){
                    env.$elts.content.css({height:env.itemHeight * env.steps.count + "px"});
                    env.$elts.content.parent().css({height:env.itemHeight * env.params.dispItems + "px"});

                } else {
                    env.$elts.content.parent().css({height:env.itemHeight + "px"});
                }

                // Update Next / Prev buttons state
                updateButtonsState(env);

                // Launch function added to "document ready" event
                jQuery.each(env.launchOnLoad, function(i,fn){
                    fn();
                });

                // Launch autoslide
                if (env.params.autoSlide){
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                        env.autoSlideInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
                            goToStep( env, getRelativeStep(env, "next") );
                        }, env.params.autoSlideInterval);
                    }, env.params.delayAutoSlide);
                }

            });

        });

    };

    // Next / Prev buttons events only
    function initButtonsEvents(env){

        env.$elts.nextBtn.add(env.$elts.prevBtn)

            .bind("enable", function(){

                var $this = jQuery(this)
                    .unbind("click")
                    .bind("click", function(){
                        goToStep( env, getRelativeStep(env, ($this.is(".next")? "next" : "prev" )) );
                        stopAutoSlide(env);
                    })
                    .removeClass("disabled");

                // Combined classes (IE6 compatibility)
                if (env.params.combinedClasses) {
                    $this.removeClass("next-disabled previous-disabled");
                }
            })
            .bind("disable", function(){

                var $this = jQuery(this).unbind("click").addClass("disabled");

                // Combined classes (IE6 compatibility)
                if (env.params.combinedClasses) {

                    if ($this.is(".next")) {
                        $this.addClass("next-disabled");

                    } else if ($this.is(".previous")) {
                        $this.addClass("previous-disabled");

                    }
                }
            })
            .hover(function(){
                jQuery(this).toggleClass("hover");
            });
    };

    // Pagination
    function initPagination(env){
        env.$elts.pagination = jQuery('<div class="center-wrap"><div class="carousel-pagination"><p></p></div></div>')[((env.params.paginationPosition == "outside")? "insertAfter" : "appendTo")](env.$elts.carousel).find("p");

        env.$elts.paginationBtns = jQuery([]);

        env.$elts.content.find("li").each(function(i){
            if (i % env.params.dispItems == 0) {
                env.$elts.paginationBtns = env.$elts.paginationBtns.add( jQuery('<a role="button"><span>'+( env.$elts.paginationBtns.length + 1 )+'</span></a>').data("firstStep", i) );
            }
        });

        env.$elts.paginationBtns.appendTo(env.$elts.pagination);

        env.$elts.paginationBtns.slice(0,1).addClass("active");

        // Events
        env.launchOnLoad.push(function(){
            env.$elts.paginationBtns.click(function(e){
                goToStep( env, jQuery(this).data("firstStep") );
                stopAutoSlide(env);
            });
        });
    };

    // Address plugin
    function initAddress(env) {

        if (env.params.useAddress && jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.address)) {

            jQuery.address
                .init(function(e) {
                    var pathNames = jQuery.address.pathNames();
                    if (pathNames[0] === env.params.adressIdentifier && !!pathNames[1]) {
                        goToStep(env, pathNames[1]-1);
                    } else {
                        jQuery.address.value('/'+ env.params.adressIdentifier +'/1');
                    }
                })
                .change(function(e) {
                    var pathNames = jQuery.address.pathNames();
                    if (pathNames[0] === env.params.adressIdentifier && !!pathNames[1]) {
                        goToStep(env, pathNames[1]-1);
                    }
                });
        } else {
            env.params.useAddress = false;
        }
    };

    function goToStep(env, step) {

        // Callback
        env.params.callback(step);

        // Launch animation
        transition(env, step);

        // Update first step
        env.steps.first = step;

        // Update buttons status
        updateButtonsState(env);

        // Update address (jQuery Address plugin)
        if ( env.params.useAddress ) {
            jQuery.address.value('/'+ env.params.adressIdentifier +'/' + (step + 1));
        }

    };

    // Get next/prev step, useful for autoSlide
    function getRelativeStep(env, position) {
        if (position == "prev") {
            if ( (env.steps.first - env.params.dispItems) >= 0 ) {
                return env.steps.first - env.params.dispItems;

            } else {
                return ( (env.params.loop)? (env.steps.count - env.params.dispItems) : false );
            }

        } else if (position == "next") {

            if ( (env.steps.first + env.params.dispItems) < env.steps.count ) {
                return env.steps.first + env.params.dispItems;

            } else {
                return ( (env.params.loop)? 0 : false );
            }
        }
    };

    // Animation
    function transition(env, step) {

        // Effect
        switch (env.params.effect){

            // No effect
            case "no":
                if (env.params.direction == "vertical"){
                    env.$elts.content.css("top", -(env.itemHeight * step) + "px");
                } else {
                    env.$elts.content.css("left", -(env.itemWidth * step) + "px");
                }
                break;

            // Fade effect
            case "fade":
                if (env.params.direction == "vertical"){
                    env.$elts.content.hide().css("top", -(env.itemHeight * step) + "px").fadeIn(env.params.animSpeed);
                } else {
                    env.$elts.content.hide().css("left", -(env.itemWidth * step) + "px").fadeIn(1000);
                }
                break;

            // Slide effect
            default:
                if (env.params.direction == "vertical"){
                    env.$elts.content.stop().animate({
                        top : -(env.itemHeight * step) + "px"
                    }, env.params.animSpeed, env.params.slideEasing);
                } else {
                    env.$elts.content.stop().animate({
                        left : -(env.itemWidth * step) + "px"
                    }, env.params.animSpeed, env.params.slideEasing);
                }
                break;
        }

    };

    // Update all buttons state : disabled or not
    function updateButtonsState(env){

        if (getRelativeStep(env, "prev") !== false) {
            env.$elts.prevBtn.trigger("enable");

        } else {
            env.$elts.prevBtn.trigger("disable");
        }

        if (getRelativeStep(env, "next") !== false) {
            env.$elts.nextBtn.trigger("enable");

        } else {
            env.$elts.nextBtn.trigger("disable");
        }

        if (env.params.pagination){
            env.$elts.paginationBtns.removeClass("active")
            .filter(function(){ return (jQuery(this).data("firstStep") == env.steps.first) }).addClass("active");
        }
    };

    // Stop autoslide
    function stopAutoSlide(env) {
        if (!!env.autoSlideInterval){
            window.clearInterval(env.autoSlideInterval);
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you tried asking the developer of this extension?

Comment: Thanks Lodder, i did they have a forum and did the post the question but been over a week now.. so thought i would try on here..